# Krumo White Screen of Death

Tags: php, var-dump, krumo

I'm trying to use [Krumo](http://krumo.sourceforge.net/) on a PHP script I'm debugging, but I'm getting a white screen of death when I actually call Krumo.

Here's what my code looks like. As far as I can tell, I'm following the instructions to install and use Krumo properly...

```
<?php ini_set('include_path', '/krumo/');?>

<?php krumo($invoice); ?>
```

For reference, I've confirmed that `$invoice` array has data. If I do a `var_dump` of it, I can crawl the data fine. I'd just prefer to use Krumo.

Comment: White screen of death? Maybe use `error reporting` on it?

Comment: `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`  There's no such thing as a white screen of death -  you just can't see your fatal error.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I was able to use error_reporting to fix my own stupid bug...turned out I was trying to include a directory that didn't exist. Embarrassing, but at least I learned about error_reporting. :)